# if statement not working properly on string data: Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a table in excel

```
    E
1  Percent score
2   80%
3   N/A
4   100%

 =IF(E2>=0.90,1,IF(E2="N/A","N/A",0))
```

So expected output (for percent >90% return flag 1, else 0, for N/A return N/A

```
         E                    F
1  Percent score             Overall flag
2   80%                        0
3   N/A                        N/A 
4   100%                        1
```

But in case of N/A also I am getting 1 as the output using this code. What to do

P.S. (edit after question being asked):
N/A is text here. It is not an actual error, it is plain text. So if we have text N/A in any cell, I would like N/A to be returned as output. Can you please help here.

Comment: Is that an actual error or just text looking like an error? A big difference, because if it's text it will evaluate to be larger than 90%, hence the `1` as output.

Comment: No its just text looking as error or N/A. How to deal with text. If there is text N/A i want N/A as output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, it looks like "N/A" is a text-string and as such evaluates to be larger than 0.9 thus returning `1`. Instead try:

```
=IF(E2="N/A",E2,--(E2>=0.9))
```

Or a more general solution to work with other text-values too:

```
=IFERROR(--(E2*1>=0.9),E2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this simply

```
=IF(E2<=0.9,0,IF(E2="N/A",E2,1))
```