# How to Sum NA (text NA) values in excel with numbers by treating NA as 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a table

```
    A           B      C
 1  Param1  Param2   Param3
 2   1        NA      NA
 3   0         1      NA
 4   0         0      NA
 5   1         NA      1
```

Expected output

```
      A           B      C     D
 1  Param1  Param2   Param3  Output
 2   1        NA      NA       3
 3   0         1      NA       2
 4   0         0      NA       1
 5   1         NA      1       3   #(sum of A,B,C columns is Output basically)
```

So basically I want excel to treat NA as 1 . NA Is text here (its not error, its plain text NA).

I tried below but doesn't work

```
=sum(A2, B2,C2)
```

This code ignores NA. I thought NA is string so will be summed too. Can you guys help

Comment: Why would Excel treat is as a number? You could use countif(range,"na").

Comment: No I want a code that sums all A,B,C columns into another column, all together

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default `COUNTIF` counts specific cells and returns a number. This gives you the ability to type in `D1 (or D2)`:

```
=COUNTIF(A3:C3,"NA")+SUM(A3:C3)
```

Which counts the number of cells that contain "NA" and then adds the sum of the numbers.

You can then drag the formula down to apply the same logic to all rows.

Answer (score 5):

In "Output" `D2`, formula copied down :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(0+TEXT(A2:C2,"0;;0;\1"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative: in the result column:

```
=SUM(IF(A3:C3="NA",1,A3:C3))
```

Comment: Don't forget, this is CSE-entered if one does not have O365.

Comment: @JvdV Point taken. To be honest, I am still discovering the possibilities of array functions now: has the potential to remove a lot of intermediate calculation columns on my worksheets (at the expense of being more difficult to follow).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest that comes to mind is to use `COUNTIF()`, probably like:

```
=3-COUNTIF(A2:D2,0)
```

Or:

```
=COUNTIF(A2:C2,"<>0")
```

---

Another little trick is to check if a cell is larger than 0:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:C2>0))
```

Since both `1` and `N/A` are larger than 0 this will evaluate to the proper amount.

If one is playing code golf and you have O365, you can do: `=SUM(--(A2:C2>0))`.

Comment: It's implied in the question (and in the data), but do we know that 0 and 1 are the only two options for the non-NA numbers?

Comment: @DS_London, good question and yes it's an assumption derived from the previous question by OP that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65214998/9758194). In general the solution provided by [sophods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65217200/9758194) is in that sense more secure!

Comment: Aha! I didn't realize you and @noob had history!